# Server can't find SAN

Tags: vmware, storage, san

One of our "newer" servers (DL380 Gen9 with HBA H241 card) can't access our SAN (P2000 G3).

In vpshere server under configuration the H241 adapter shows the devices but the data storage cannot be added. None of the 4 LUNs is found there: [Devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALGV6.png) and [data storages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKeGQ.png)

That's how it looks for the other machines: [data storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrVbe.png)

Any idea on how to add the storage? I'm working on it for quite some time and have even tried one of the storage adapters of the working machines in the new server without success. As far as I can tell the adapter is mapped correctly to all storage units, but I'm far from experienced and can't put my finger on the cause.

Additionally, does anyone have suggestions for lectures on this topic? I've come to a client that has the system described and I would like to get the necessary know how on the system.

Comment: Yes, there are 4 datastores, which are used by 2 other machines in the cluster. The 3rd screenshot shows the datastores, that are available for those machines. The server in question can find those disks, but can't connect to the data stores on those disks.